# Deciding on ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

see the code below, it work really. 
It insert into `affiliate` table if a record do not exist.
If it has been inserted in `affiliate` table then it will add a new record in `phone` table. However it will need to update `phone_id` field in `affiliate` table (new recent record) on the 3rd query - is there a way to reduce this?

```
$SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO affiliate (affiliate_id, affiliate_phone_id, stock) ";
$SQLInsert .= "VALUES ('1', '$affiliatePhoneID', '$stock') ";
$SQLInsert .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stock = '$stock'";
mysql_query($SQLInsert);
if (mysql_insert_id()) {
    $SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO phone (name) VALUE('$phoneName')";
    $q = mysql_query($SQLInsert);

    // If a record has been inserted into affiliate table and then phone table
    // then it need to update phone_id field in affiliate table. 
    $phone_id = mysql_insert_id();
    $SQLUpdate = "UPDATE affiliate set phone_id = $phone_id WHERE affiliate_id = 1 AND affiliate_phone_id = '$affiliatePhoneID'";
    mysql_query($SQLUpdate) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: You could use a trigger to do the last update, but it will still be making a database call in the background - your code just won't have to worry about it.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce this? I mean it's already looking quite compact IMHO. If you would wrap it into a function of it's own it might be even more speaking, but what are you concerned about?

Comment: Also `mysql_insert_id` might be misleading if you have MySQL queries before the first query that do insert things as per the connection because of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. See the notes on the `mysql_insert_id()` function.

Comment: @hakra Yea maybe you are right, maybe I am being too fussy trying to look perfect. Maybe logic is already look good :)

Comment: @hakra I notice there is a problem. `affiliate_id` and `affiliate_phone_id` is unique keys. When I update the new value of `stock` - why it inserting a new record? I expect to update only.

Comment: And what is the primary key of the affiliate table?

Comment: @hakra `affiliate.id` is a primary key. I meant it insert a new record in `phone` table when `stock` field have been updated from `affiliate` table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16964/discussion-between-ill-be-back-and-hakra)

Comment: `if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) { }` seem fixed the problem.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back: Please add your solution as an answer below (yes that's accepted and common), I suggest with your code-example from above updated after you've given some little description what and why this fixed it for you. Thank you, and sorry I was thinking about affected rows but then thought this is not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change the database sheme so the phone table holds the forainkey to the affilaite table. so you dont need to update the affilate table twice.

If that is not what you want, you could try to UPDATE the phone table first,
and after that the affilate table.